# Http cannot access all headers properties

Tags: javascript, http, typescript, http-headers

I'm trying to get a specific property `Link` from http response headers, in Postman I can see 17 properties in the headers, but when I log the headers object in my app I get like half of them only. How can I get the rest?

[image]

Same request in Postman

[image]

I'm using Typescript

```
private fetch = (): Observable<Response> => {

    return this.http.get(this.endpoint, this.queryArgs).map(
        (res) => {

            console.log(res.headers);
            /** Notify subscriber with the new pagination */
            this.pagination.next(this.setPagination(res.headers));
            return res.json();
        }
    );
}
```